# I'm having trouble making an object where its properties are objects(and their properties are objects...so on)

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, nested-object

Right now I'm writing code as kind of a test for handling data.  I'm using shorter arrays than what I'm actually going to be handling and I'm having trouble with it and I think I know whats wrong but it's kind of like brain fart and I can't actually find the problem.  Any help is appreciated so thank you in advance.

```
if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('log')) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'log', {
    get: function() {
      console.log(this);

    }
  });
}

if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getProps')) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'getProps', {
    get: function() {
      //console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this));
      return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
    }
  });
}

function appendItem(list, item) {
  list.push(item);
}

var cities = ["Houston", "Dallas", "Rockwall", "Bossier", "Shreveport"];
var dates = ["monday", "monday", "monday", "monday", "monday"];
var states = ["Texas", "Texas", "Texas", "Louisiana", "Louisiana"];


function Setup(obj, sub, thisArg) {
  obj.forEach(function(key, index) {
    if ((this[key] == undefined)) {
      this[key] = [sub[index]];
    } else {
      appendItem(this[key], sub[index]);
    }
  }, thisArg);
  return obj;
}
var weather = {};
Setup(dates, states, weather);
weather.log;
Setup(states, cities, weather);
weather.log;
```

The result that I'm wanting is something that's accomplishes this:

```
weather = {monday:{Texas:["Houston", "Dallas", "Rockwall"], Louisiana:["Bossier", "Shreveport"]}};
```

but in the form of a loop or function because the actual data that I'm going to use when I figure this out is way larger.  This is the actual output that I'm getting though:

```js
if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('log')) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'log', {
    get: function() {
      console.log(this);

    }
  });
}

if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getProps')) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'getProps', {
    get: function() {
      //console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this));
      return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
    }
  });
}

function appendItem(list, item) {
  list.push(item);
}

var cities = ["Houston", "Dallas", "Rockwall", "Bossier", "Shreveport"];
var dates = ["monday", "monday", "monday", "monday", "monday"];
var states = ["Texas", "Texas", "Texas", "Louisiana", "Louisiana"];


function Setup(obj, sub, thisArg) {
  obj.forEach(function(key, index) {
    if ((this[key] == undefined)) {
      this[key] = [sub[index]];
    } else {
      appendItem(this[key], sub[index]);
    }
  }, thisArg);
  return obj;
}
var weather = {};
Setup(dates, states, weather);
weather.log;
Setup(states, cities, weather);
weather.log;
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't work out what your code was doing, but based on your example output, you just need a single loop, and chain the values together.

eg..

```js
var cities = ["Houston", "Dallas", "Rockwall", "Bossier", "Shreveport"];
var dates = ["monday", "monday", "monday", "monday", "monday"];
var states = ["Texas", "Texas", "Texas", "Louisiana", "Louisiana"];


var weather = {};

for (var l = 0; l < cities.length; l += 1) {
  //day
  var d = weather[dates[l]] =
    weather[dates[l]] || {};  
  //state
  var s = d[states[l]] = 
    d[states[l]] || [];
  //cities
  s.push(cities[l]);
}

console.log(weather);
```

Comment: this is really close but is there a way that uses a recursive function instead? If not I can make this work but either way thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can display the output in a different way, such as by passing the vars to console.log() as:

**console.log(weather);**

or by pretty formatting it:

**console.log(JSON.stringify(weather));**

If you want to proceed, you shall note how is the data at your input arrays,
if it leads to as a tree or a graph. After analysing your situation a possible solution, if the input data is of tree type with depth=3, that I propose is:

```
<script>
function append_item(list, item) {
  list.push(item);
}

var dates = ["monday", "monday", "monday", "monday", "monday"];
var states = ["Texas", "Texas", "Texas", "Louisiana", "Louisiana"];
var cities = ["Houston", "Dallas", "Rockwall", "Bossier", "Shreveport"];


function setup(obj, sub, this_arg) {
  obj.forEach(function(key, index) {
    if ((this[key] == undefined)) {
      this[key] = [sub[index]];
    } else if (!this[key].includes(sub[index])){
      append_item(this[key], sub[index]);
    }
  }, this_arg);
  return obj;
}


weather = {};
setup(dates, states, weather);

var sub_dict = {};
setup(states, cities, sub_dict);

var obj_values = Object.values(weather);
for (i=0; i<obj_values.length; i++){
    var x=obj_values[i];
    for (j=0; j<obj_values[i].length; j++){
        var y=obj_values[i][j];
        obj_values[i][j] = {};
        obj_values[i][j][y] = sub_dict[y];
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(weather));
</script>
```

The output of this code is:

```
{"monday":[{"Texas":["Houston","Dallas","Rockwall"]},{"Louisiana":["Bossier","Shreveport"]}]}
```

(note that this format is reduced as you want, but slightly different in the format).